An easy proof of weak*-weak* continuity of the canonical mapping $\psi: X^*\to X^{***}$
I was trying to prove that the canonical mapping $\psi: X^*\to X^{***}$ is $\text{weak*-weak*}$ continuous. I have tried in the following way:
Let $\{x_\alpha^*\}$ be a net in $X^*$ such that $x_\alpha^*\xrightarrow[\alpha]{\text{weak*}} x^*\in X^{*}$. Clearly, $\{\psi(x_\alpha^*)\}\in X^{***}$. We claim that $\psi(x_\alpha^*)\xrightarrow[\alpha]{\text{weak*}} \psi(x^*)\in X^{***}$. For any $f\in X^{****}$,
\begin{equation}
|f(\psi(x_\alpha^*))-f(\psi (x^*))|\leq \|f\|\|\psi(x_\alpha^*)-\psi(x^*)\|.\qquad \qquad (A)
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{split}
\|\psi(x_\alpha^*)-\psi(x^*)\|&=\sup_{\gamma\in B_{X^{**}}}|\psi(x_\alpha^*)(\gamma)-\psi(x^*)(\gamma)|\\
&=\sup_{\gamma\in B_{X^{**}}}|\gamma(x_\alpha^*)-\gamma(x^*)|\\
&=\max_{\gamma\in B_{X^{**}}}|\gamma(x_\alpha^*)-\gamma(x^*)|\qquad \quad (\text{Since}~B_{X^{**}} ~\text{is weak* compact})\\
& =|\gamma_0(x_\alpha^*)-\gamma_0(x^*)|,~\text{for some $\gamma_0\in B_{X^{**}}$}\\
& \longrightarrow 0\qquad\text{as}\qquad \alpha\longrightarrow\infty\qquad (\text{Since}~x_\alpha^*\xrightarrow[\alpha]{\text{weak*}} x^*).
\end{split}
Therefore, it follows from $(A)$ that $\psi(x_\alpha^*)\xrightarrow[\alpha]{\text{weak*}} \psi(x^*)\in X^{***}$.
Firstly, please tell me if the proof is rightfully attempted. If wrong, then how can we conclude our claim? Is there any alternative way to conclude this? Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The thesis as it's stated should not be true in general.
If you consider the copy of $X^*$ in $X^{***}$, the $w^*$ topology of $X^{***}$ induces on it the $w$ topology of $X^*$ (this should be very easy). But the $w^*$ topology of $X^*$ topology is rougher than the $w$ one. So the map you are talking about is continuous if and only if $X$ is reflexive.
EDIT (to answer the comment):
What I proved is that you have the continuity $w-w^*$, basically because they both refer to $X^{**}$.
However the $w-w$ one is true too: the subspace topology of the copy of $X^*$ has the topology induced by the functionals in $X^{****}$ restricted to $X^*$, but this are just bounded functionals and $X^{**}$ already contains all of them. Moreover by Hahn-Banach you can see that for all the functionals in $X^{**}$ there is a functional in $X^{****}$ which coincides with the first one on $X^*$.
So the subspace topology of the copy of $X^*$ is still the $w$ one (even if the topology of $X^{***}$ is finer than before). So in this case the map is actually continuous.
Remark: Note that in the cases $w-w^*$ and $w-w$ I also proved that these maps are embeddings (homeomorphisms with the images).

Many thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused. I think if the question asked whether the given canonical map is weak-weak continuous then my written proof should be ok by replacing all '$\text{weak*}$' terms with 'weak'. Am I right? Or, again for weak-weak continuity, we required the reflexivity condition?

@Tuh I edited the answer.

Thank you once again.

Another reason to see why reflexivity is required: By the universal property of the weak(-star) topology, $\psi$ is $w^$-to-$w^$ continuous if and only if $x^{} \circ \psi \colon X^* \to \mathbb R$ is weak-star continuous for all $x^{} \in X^{}$. Since $x^{} \circ \psi = x^{}$ you see that this happens if and only if each $x^{}\in X^{**}$ is weak-star continuous, i.e. $X$ is reflexive.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos yes and this kind of argument is also implicit in what I said, because I used the fact that a weak topology induced by a subspace V of the functionals is such that the only continuous functionals are exactly the elements of V.

@MatteoGori can you please point out one more thing when the said canonical mapping becomes $w^*-w$ continuous?

@Tuh For all the things I said, in this case the copy of $X^$ in $X^{*}$ has its usual $w$ topology. So the map is continuous iff $X$ is reflexive (since you need $w^$ to be finer than $w$).

@MatteoGori that means for $w-w$, $w-w^$ we do not need reflexivity. But when we need $w^-w^$, $w^-w$ continuity we must need the reflexivity of $X$, as we need $w^*$ to be finer than $w$. This is the conclusion, right?

@Tuh yes you are right.

@MatteoGori Thank you for your detailed discussions.
